# Generate vagrant file from a running server

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, puppet

Maybe i'm asking a stupid question, but i'm wondering if it's possible to generate a vagrant file from a development server that is already running. I'm asking because the software that we are making has ZERO documentation and i'm making a VM with vagrant and puppet but i don't know all the dependency that the software needs to run successfully.

So my question is can you automatically create a vagrant file that is a perfect clone of a server ? It's Linux centOs server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo puppet resource package
```

can get you as far as at least knowing what versions of what packages your server is running.
Put that in a Puppet manifest and you already have something decent to work with.